# Why is my for loop not working on my Javascript properties?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I created this object and it's properties:

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty( obj, "value", {
  value: true,
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});

var name = "John";

Object.defineProperty( obj, "name", {
  get: function(){ return name; },
  set: function(value){ name = value; }
});
```

So then I call a for loop on them:

```
for ( var prop in obj ) {
  console.log( prop );
}
```

Which according to my tutorial, should produce the following results:

```
value
name
```

But instead it only displays value. Why is name not showing up?

Comment: Please accept one of answers which is solved your problem. This help other user in future when they face this problem ..:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default value for `enumerable` in `defineProperty` is `false`; non-enumerable properties do not show up in `for…in` loops. (That's the whole point of the `enumerable` flag.) If you add `enumerable:true` into your second definition also, it will 'fix' it.

See [some docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 5):

Because the name property is not defined as enumerable, set the name definition to

```
Object.defineProperty( obj, "name", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function(){ return name; },
  set: function(value){ name = value; }
});
```

and it will show up.